# TF285017: The Assigned To field cannot be blank

Tags: tfs, project-server

I'm working with TFS 2010 and Project 2010 Feature Integration pack and the Scrum for Team System v3 process template.  Within the Project Server tab, I'm trying to set the default value for "Submit to Project Server" and "Enterprise Project" (which works fine), but when the Project Backlog Item is created/saved, it always fails when trying to sync with Project Server with the error message in the title of this post: TF285017: The Assigned To field cannot be blank.

I've Googled the error code, and it seems like there is no documentation for it anywhere.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately I fixed by adding the Assigned To field to the template and making it required.  This probably isn't the best way to solve this issue, but does get around the error (and making the field required was something I was going to do anyway).

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, in the TFS process template for the backlog item, the Assigned To field is mandatory. It needs to be filled before it can be synced with the other system.

You might try to remove the required flag from the Assigned To field in the workitem by using the TFS Power Tools process editor.